# Send windows key in vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I've looked everywhere for this, is it actually possible to do? If you press WIN + LEFT ARROW it will mount your selected window to the left of your screen, and that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have tried things like:

```
shl.sendkeys "#{LEFT}"
```

Because I found out that `#` could be for WIN just like `+` is for Shift and `%` is for Alt.

This may be a stupid question but it would help me out so much. Thank you for you time

Answer (score 7):

```
Set Keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Keys.SendKeys("^{Esc}")
```

This should work, it Simulates the push of the Windows key by pushing the CTRL `^` and the ESC  `{Esc}`keys, i don't know how to make the window mount to the left of the screen

Comment: Ctrl+Esc doesn't simulate the Win key; it just opens the Start menu.

Comment: It blocked in Windows 10 in my machine.

Answer (score 7):

VBScript's `SendKeys` doesn't support the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

You can use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com) instead:

```
Send("{#Left}")
```

Answer (score 3):

***Oh***, *so you want to mount the window to the left*, I currently don't think there's a way to do that, but there's another shortcut for start menu, as well as windows key, it's Ctrl+Esc, `^{ESC}`, you could possibly run the onscreen keyboard, then somehow tab over to the key, but it would be hard, *also* how about trying Alt+Space, `%{SPACE}`, to click the window icon then, `M` for move, then set the cursors position to the left of the screen, somehow? I don't currently need help moving the cursor in V.B.S., but you could [Google](https://www.google.ca/) it. **Hash** symbol is actually typing the symbol *`#`*, *hash*, tested with *[this](https://keycode.info/)*. I also got help on the send-keys function, **[here](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**. I have *way* to much researching, but I **still** can't find a answer. Some-one also said using "[Auto hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)", a third party program, but I don't really trust programs that can take control over **your *whole*** PC.

---

So I guess your options are:

- Alt+Space to click window icon, then M for move, then move cursor to left side of the screen
- [Auto HotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), although I don't recommend it.
- Other commands, but SendKeys, in VBS,
- Running a file, built in a different language to do so.
- Or well, waiting-for / asking [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au) to add it in, in the next version of [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows)?!

Answer (score 1):

a very late response, but here is my working effort

```
Dim shellObject : Set shellObject = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Extern.Declare micVoid, "keybd_event", "user32.dll", "keybd_event", micByte, micByte, micLong, micLong
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Const VK_LWIN = &H5B

Wait 5
Call Extern.keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,0,0) 'press win key
Wait 5
shellObject.SendKeys  "({UP})" 'right aline the window. TODO Error handlng
Wait 5
Call Extern.keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) 'up win key
Set shellObject = Nothing
```

Comment: You can't use Extern.Declare in vbscript

Answer (score -1):

try this
`wshshell.sendkeys "{lwin}"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).